# Init Script for Testcontainers doesn't work properly

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, testcontainers

As I mention in title, I got problem with Init Script for Testcontainers.

Script content:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dbo_core;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo_core.company (
    ID BIGINT generated by default as identity primary key,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) not null
);

INSERT INTO dbo_core.company (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Company1');
```

After looking inside the docker by command:

```
docker exec -it cranky_ramanujan psql -Utest
```

The result is:

```
test=# select * from dbo_core.company;
 id | name 
----+------
(0 rows)
```

Does anybody know what should I improve?
Thank you in advance. :)

EDIT.

CompanyDaoTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(classes = OutCaloriesCoreApplication.class)
public class CompanyDaoTest {

    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer> postgreSQLContainer = OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer.getInstance().withInitScript("db-init-script.sql");

    @Autowired
    private CompanyDao companyDao;

    @BeforeAll
    static void init() {
        postgreSQLContainer.start();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void findByIdShouldEndWithSuccess() {
        Company byId = companyDao.findById(1L);
        assertEquals(byId.getId(), 1L);
    }
}
```

OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer.java:

```
public class OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer extends PostgreSQLContainer<OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer> {
    private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "postgres:11.1";

    private static OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer container;

    private OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
    }

    public static OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new OutCaloriesPostgresqlContainer();

        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //do nothing, JVM handles shut down
    }
}
```

Testcontainers version is 1.15.3.

Logs: https://pastebin.com/qgrPb3JL

Comment: Can you please add your test class, Testcontainers version, and the log output for your test? Furthermore, this [overview of initialization strategies with Testcontainers] might also help to get the setup right.

Comment: at which location do you store your init script? `src/test/resources`? It seems that I failed to link the blog post that might help here, here's the link to the [overview of initialization strategies with Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/initialization-strategies-with-testcontainers-for-integration-tests/) again

Comment: I found out the problem. The reason for empty table, was that I had spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto set as create-drop and it overrided tables created by init script. Now it works. Thanks. :)

Comment: that's perfect. You can self-answer your question here on Stack Overflow and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Cool. Nice idea. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the empty table was a setting "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" property on "create-drop".
It makes that tables and values created by init script was overrode by new tables generated by hibernate.
In my case, best solution was just set this property as "none".